# Coordinates of frustum corners

Tags: opengl, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, frustum

A method for extracting the 6 plane equations of a viewing frustum given by a MVP matrix is given by [this](http://gamedevs.org/uploads/fast-extraction-viewing-frustum-planes-from-world-view-projection-matrix.pdf).
It there a similar method known for getting the world space coordinates of its 8 corner points, directly out of the 4x4 MVP matrix and without using trigonometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by multiplying the projected coordinates of the frustum corners e.g. (1, -1, -1) with the inverse MVP matrix.

**Edit:**

If an [OpenGL-type projection matrix P](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) is used, the coordinates `c` of the frustum's corners in model space are `(±1, ±1, ±1)` (inside the frustum each coordinate goes from -1 to +1).

The corresponding coordinates in world space can be calculated as `(P * V * M)^(-1) * c`. (in homogeneous coordinates)

Comment: please more details about projected coordinates

Comment: @lady: added details

Comment: What is M, the model matrix, in this case?

Comment: @livin_amuk would just be the identity matrix